# #if !DEBUG [RequireHttps] does not work on the server

Tags: asp.net-mvc

To change the checkout page URL from HTTP to HTTPS (SSL) I am using:

```
  #if !DEBUG
    [RequireHttps]
  #endif
```

The problem is that the page is not redirected from HTTP to HTTPS.

But when I removed the `#if` statement and use only  `[RequireHttps]`, then the page successfully redirected to HTTPS.

I am still developing the site so I want to keep it `#if` statement.

What could it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't confuse the ASP.NET debug setting (in Web.config) with the C# debug mode setting (in Solution Configuration). They are entirely different, and one does not affect the other. `#if !DEBUG` is controlled by the Solution Configuration, not the ASP.NET / Web.config debug mode and must be changed before compiling your code.